# How to identify scope of static variable?

Tags: c, static, bootloader

I'm trying to understand a basic bootloader. Here is a function that is called in a while loop:

```
static void uart_task(void)
{
  static int ptr = 0;
  static int command = 0;
  static int size = 0;
  uint8_t *byte_buf = (uint8_t *)uart_buffer;
  int data;

  if (uart_command)
    return;

  if (0 == UART_SERCOM->USART.INTFLAG.bit.RXC)
    return;

  data = UART_SERCOM->USART.DATA.reg;

  if (timer_expired())
    command = 0;

  if (0 == command)
  {
    ptr = 0;
    command = data;
    uart_buffer[0] = 0;

    if (BL_CMD_UNLOCK == command)
      size = CMD_UNLOCK_SIZE;
    else if (BL_CMD_DATA == command)
      size = CMD_DATA_SIZE;
    else if (BL_CMD_VERIFY == command)
      size = CMD_VERIFY_SIZE;
    else if (BL_CMD_RESET == command)
      size = CMD_RESET_SIZE;
    else
      size = 0;
  }
  else if (ptr < size)
  {
    byte_buf[ptr++] = data;
  }

  if (ptr == size)
  {
    uart_command = command;
    command = 0;
  }

  timer_reset();
}
```

`static int command = 0` is initialized at the top of the function.

16 lines down `command`'s value is checked; `if (0 == command)`.

Won't that `if` statement always return true? How could `command`'s value be changed between its declaration and its value being checked?

Comment: `static` objects keep their value between function invocations: `void foo(void) { static int k = 0; printf("k is %d\n", k); k++; } int main(void) { foo(); foo(); foo(); foo(); }`. In your example, `command` is changed after the `if`

Comment: `static` does not change scope. The scope of your example identifier `command` is the function it is declared in: the object cannot be accessed by that identifier from anywhere else. `static` changes the object lifetime: your object exists (but cannot be accessed) from program start until program end.

Comment: Its value is changed by `command = data;` The initialisation `static int command = 0;` is performed only *once*, not every time the function is called.

Comment: @WeatherVane: Once per program execution, not once. That would be a neat trick.

Comment: @EricPostpischil perhaps once per linker operation?

Comment: @WeatherVane: Still a neat trick. Suppose you link it, email me a copy, and run the program, after which `command` is set to 1. I run the program and, lo and behold, `command` is already 1!

Comment: @EricPostpischil quantum computing. The value is thinly smeared.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`static` variables keep their value between function invocations. In addition, they are not initialized at the start of the function; they have their value from the start of the program.

For example, with a static variable,

```
int foo(int bar)
{
    static int baz = 0;

    if(bar)
        baz = 1;

    return baz;
}
```

is not the same as,

```
int foo(int bar)
{
    static int baz;

    baz = 0;

    if(bar)
        baz = 1;

    return baz;
}
```

In the first example, when `foo` is called with a nonzero argument, it will return `1` from that invocation and any subsequent invocations. In the second, `foo` only returns `1` when it is passed a nonzero argument, and always returns `0` otherwise.

In your case, `command` is changed right here:

```
  if (0 == command)
  {
    ptr = 0;
    command = data; // here
    uart_buffer[0] = 0;
```

and, unless `ptr == size` or the timer has expired, it will keep that value for the next call.